# SVM: Would we care about the functional margin if maximizing only with geometric margin were convex?

Tags: optimization, svm, convex

I am reading Andrew Ng's SVM notes (https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes3.pdf) and am lacking the intuition for why we need the functional margin. As far as I understand we need it as the following optimization problem expressed only in terms of the geometric margin is not convex:

$max_{\gamma, w, b} = \gamma$

such that $y_{i}(w^{T}x + b) \geq \gamma $ $i = 1 \ldots m$

and $\lvert \lvert w \rvert \rvert = 1$

The constraint $\lvert \lvert w \rvert \rvert = 1$ is not convex. Suppose for the sake of understanding the importance of the functional margin that  $\lvert \lvert w \rvert \rvert = 1$ is convex and we can directly optimize this problem. Could we then entirely forget about the concept of the functional margin? In other words, do we only need the notion of a functional margin, as it allows us to rewrite the above equation as a convex optimization problem?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the single constraint $||w||^2 = 1$ actually has zero-duality gap.

However, a simpler explanation can help for this situation. We can actually solve instead for $||w||^2 \leq 1$, which is convex. To see this, note though that if $||w||^2 < 1$ then if I multiply $\gamma$ and $w$ by some factor $\beta > 1$ that I maintain the constraint, and improve the objective. Thus, given any valid solution having $0 < ||w||^2 < 1$, I can simply multiply through by $\beta = \frac{1}{||w||^2}$ to maximize the objective, for $w$ pointing in "that direction". Thus, the constraint $||w||=1$ can actually be replaced by the convex $||w||^2 \leq 1$.